# Task status :Waiting for activation -DownloadStringTaskAsync -WP8

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, task, async-await

The status of task is always "Waiting for activation".The Result of the task ="".
i dont understand why...Thanks for your help
The UI calls the GetDocLibs method.

```
public class ServerFunctions
{
    public static List<BdeskDocLib> GetDocLibs(bool onlyDocLibPerso)
    {
        string xmlContent = GetXml();
        List<BdeskDocLib> result = BdeskDocLib.GetListFromXml(xmlContent,  onlyDocLibPerso);
        return result;
    }

   private static String GetXml()
    {  
        Task<String>task=requesteur.Query(dataRequestParam);
        task.Wait();
        xmlResult = task.Result;
        return xmlResult;
    }
}

public class DataRequest
{
    public Task<String> Query(DataRequestParam dataRequestParam)
    {
       try
       {
        WebClient web = new WebClient();    
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRequestParam.AuthentificationLogin))
        {
            System.Net.NetworkCredential account = new NetworkCredential(dataRequestParam.AuthentificationLogin, dataRequestParam.AuthentificationPassword);
            web.Credentials = account;
        }
        return  web.DownloadStringTaskAsync(dataRequestParam.TargetUri).ConfigureAwait(false); 
     }  
 catch(WebException we)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(we.Message);
            return null;
        }
   } 
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a deadlock and your Task cannot be started. Can you add some more code, especially how the GetXml method is called?

Comment: This code won't even compile, you have `try` without `catch`/`finally`. Show the rest.

Comment: I had only written the code which i think is involved in the issue...but now i added the catch...

Comment: Read [this post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html "Don't Block on Async Code ") from [Stephen Cleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary).

Comment: yes i know this article ...i tried with the ConfigureAwait(false) but still the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All my methods need to be async.

```
public class ServerFunctions
{
    public static async Task<List<BdeskDocLib>> GetDocLibs(bool onlyDocLibPerso)
    {
        string xmlContent = await GetXml();
        List<BdeskDocLib> result = BdeskDocLib.GetListFromXml(xmlContent,  onlyDocLibPerso);
        return result;
    }

   private async static Task<String> GetXml()
    {  
        Task<String>task=requesteur.Query(dataRequestParam);
        task.Wait();
        xmlResult = task.Result;
        return xmlResult;
    }
}
```